# Navigation drawer extending base activity

Tags: android, user-interface

I have created a baseactivity with a navigation drawer and searchview. I am trying to extend this in other activities, but also have different content. However if I extend the base activity, and try to set a different content view, I don't get the navigation drawer/search view.

How do i extend the baseactivity, but still customize the ui for each activity?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use Fragments. However, to use multiple activities, extend the base activity and then use setContentView() with the layout for that activity. Ensure that the xml for that layout contains the navigation drawer layout too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I extend the base activity, and setContentView(), my activity is not working fully, and I just have to duplicate the code to get the navigation drawer to work(Display options in drawer, use home button etc.) What am I gaining by extending the activity?

Comment: Can you show us the base class that you're created ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do something like this. You'll see that any of the Activities that inherit from this one and call setContentView will now be adding their content to the content frame in your already inflated navigation layout.

```
public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private FrameLayout mContentFrame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // notice we call super.setContentView here
        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // and other nav stuff here

        mContentFrame = findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID)
    {
        setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, mContentFrame, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view)
    {
        mContentFrame.removeAllViews();
        mContentFrame.addView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, LayoutParams params)
    {
        mContentFrame.removeAllViews();
        addContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void addContentView(View view, LayoutParams params)
    {
        mContentFrame.addView(view, params);
    }
}
```